# Suspend not working anymore - flashing login screen instead

Tags: 22.04, suspend

Since a few weeks I have an issue with suspending my ThinkPad T15p laptop. Two scenarios:

- Closing the lid. The red dot on the back of the laptop always stays on and never goes into the "sleeping" (glowing / fading) state. When I open the lid again, I see the login screen flashing with the time of closing the lid (or a few seconds after). Then black screen, then flashing of the login screen with time of closing the lid, then black screen, ... and so on. I cannot interrupt this loop. What I **can** actually do is press Ctrl+Alt+F[1-12] and use another tty console.
- Use `systemctl suspend`. That just logs me out of my session and I see the login screen. When I login, indeed my session is saved and I can continue working. But in that case I never closed my lid.

I will neglect the second case for now as it's not my use case anyway and was rather a test. Here is the syslog when I close the lid at 20:13:00:

```
Dec 12 20:13:00 thinkstation gnome-shell[2771]: Failed to use stored monitor configuration: Invalid mode 3840x2160 (59,968498) for monitor 'CSO 0x1500'
Dec 12 20:13:00 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408380.2314] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Dec 12 20:13:00 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408380.2317] device (84:CF:BF:93:7A:07): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 12 20:13:00 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408380.2324] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 12 20:13:00 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408380.2332] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Dec 12 20:13:00 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408380.2335] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 12 20:13:00 thinkstation dbus-daemon[929]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.7' (uid=0 pid=930 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Dec 12 20:13:00 thinkstation systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Dec 12 20:13:00 thinkstation dbus-daemon[929]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Dec 12 20:13:00 thinkstation systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Dec 12 20:13:00 thinkstation kernel: [ 1249.237381] wlp0s20f3: deauthenticating from 18:d6:c7:f9:e7:6e by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Dec 12 20:13:00 thinkstation wpa_supplicant[979]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=18:d6:c7:f9:e7:6e reason=3 locally_generated=1
Dec 12 20:13:00 thinkstation wpa_supplicant[979]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Dec 12 20:13:00 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408380.4346] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 12 20:13:00 thinkstation avahi-daemon[923]: Withdrawing address record for fd5c:eae6:5382::acb on wlp0s20f3.
Dec 12 20:13:00 thinkstation avahi-daemon[923]: Withdrawing address record for fd5c:eae6:5382:0:7c41:544a:7371:7c8d on wlp0s20f3.
Dec 12 20:13:00 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408380.4361] dhcp4 (wlp0s20f3): canceled DHCP transaction
Dec 12 20:13:00 thinkstation avahi-daemon[923]: Withdrawing address record for fd5c:eae6:5382:0:e4cd:4b2e:f79b:7916 on wlp0s20f3.
Dec 12 20:13:00 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408380.4362] dhcp4 (wlp0s20f3): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Dec 12 20:13:00 thinkstation avahi-daemon[923]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp0s20f3.IPv6 with address fd5c:eae6:5382:0:e4cd:4b2e:f79b:7916.
Dec 12 20:13:00 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408380.4362] dhcp4 (wlp0s20f3): state changed no lease
Dec 12 20:13:00 thinkstation avahi-daemon[923]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp0s20f3.IPv6 with address fe80::6b6b:590d:c2f2:58a7.
Dec 12 20:13:00 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408380.4368] dhcp6 (wlp0s20f3): canceled DHCP transaction
Dec 12 20:13:00 thinkstation avahi-daemon[923]: Registering new address record for fe80::6b6b:590d:c2f2:58a7 on wlp0s20f3.*.
Dec 12 20:13:00 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408380.4369] dhcp6 (wlp0s20f3): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Dec 12 20:13:00 thinkstation avahi-daemon[923]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::6b6b:590d:c2f2:58a7 on wlp0s20f3.
Dec 12 20:13:00 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408380.4369] dhcp6 (wlp0s20f3): state changed no lease
Dec 12 20:13:00 thinkstation avahi-daemon[923]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp0s20f3.IPv6 with address fe80::6b6b:590d:c2f2:58a7.
Dec 12 20:13:00 thinkstation avahi-daemon[923]: Interface wlp0s20f3.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Dec 12 20:13:00 thinkstation avahi-daemon[923]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.1.115 on wlp0s20f3.
Dec 12 20:13:00 thinkstation avahi-daemon[923]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp0s20f3.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.115.
Dec 12 20:13:00 thinkstation avahi-daemon[923]: Interface wlp0s20f3.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Dec 12 20:13:00 thinkstation systemd-resolved[774]: wlp0s20f3: Bus client reset search domain list.
Dec 12 20:13:00 thinkstation systemd-resolved[774]: wlp0s20f3: Bus client set default route setting: no
Dec 12 20:13:00 thinkstation systemd-resolved[774]: wlp0s20f3: Bus client reset DNS server list.
Dec 12 20:13:00 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408380.4809] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Dec 12 20:13:00 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408380.4838] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 12 20:13:00 thinkstation gnome-shell[2771]: ../../../gobject/gsignal.c:2765: instance '0x56258dc48d70' has no handler with id '200884'
Dec 12 20:13:00 thinkstation wpa_supplicant[979]: p2p-dev-wlp0s20: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Dec 12 20:13:00 thinkstation wpa_supplicant[979]: p2p-dev-wlp0s20: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Dec 12 20:13:00 thinkstation wpa_supplicant[979]: nl80211: deinit ifname=p2p-dev-wlp0s20 disabled_11b_rates=0
Dec 12 20:13:00 thinkstation wpa_supplicant[979]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Dec 12 20:13:00 thinkstation wpa_supplicant[979]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Dec 12 20:13:00 thinkstation wpa_supplicant[979]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlp0s20f3 disabled_11b_rates=0
Dec 12 20:13:01 thinkstation gnome-shell[2771]: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
Dec 12 20:13:04 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408384.1070] manager: sleep: wake requested (sleeping: yes  enabled: yes)
Dec 12 20:13:04 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408384.1071] device (enp0s31f6): state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 12 20:13:04 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408384.1920] device (enp0s31f6): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Dec 12 20:13:04 thinkstation kernel: [ 1253.106141] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 enp0s31f6: NIC Link is Down
Dec 12 20:13:04 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408384.3823] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Dec 12 20:13:04 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408384.5865] device (84:CF:BF:93:7A:07): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Dec 12 20:13:04 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408384.5872] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Dec 12 20:13:04 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408384.5878] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Dec 12 20:13:04 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408384.5885] device (84:CF:BF:93:7A:07): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 12 20:13:04 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408384.6462] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: internal-starting -> disconnected
Dec 12 20:13:04 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408384.6463] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason 'removed', sys-iface-state: 'removed')
Dec 12 20:13:04 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408384.6474] Wi-Fi P2P device controlled by interface wlp0s20f3 created
Dec 12 20:13:04 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408384.6480] manager: (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): new 802.11 Wi-Fi P2P device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/7)
Dec 12 20:13:04 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408384.6487] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Dec 12 20:13:04 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408384.6498] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 12 20:13:04 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408384.6510] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 12 20:13:04 thinkstation gnome-shell[2771]: Removing a network device that was not added
Dec 12 20:13:07 thinkstation wpa_supplicant[979]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=DRIVER type=COUNTRY alpha2=DE
Dec 12 20:13:07 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408387.7207] policy: auto-activating connection 'OpenWrtP87' (4a614355-1a04-400c-a028-581aa3f12450)
Dec 12 20:13:07 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408387.7210] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: starting connection 'OpenWrtP87' (4a614355-1a04-400c-a028-581aa3f12450)
Dec 12 20:13:07 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408387.7210] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 12 20:13:07 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408387.7212] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Dec 12 20:13:07 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408387.7213] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 12 20:13:07 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408387.7215] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) access point 'OpenWrtP87' has security, but secrets are required.
Dec 12 20:13:07 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408387.7215] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 12 20:13:07 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408387.7221] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 12 20:13:07 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408387.7223] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 12 20:13:07 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408387.7225] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) connection 'OpenWrtP87' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Dec 12 20:13:07 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408387.7225] Config: added 'ssid' value 'OpenWrtP87'
Dec 12 20:13:07 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408387.7225] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Dec 12 20:13:07 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408387.7225] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
Dec 12 20:13:07 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408387.7225] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK SAE FT-SAE'
Dec 12 20:13:07 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408387.7225] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Dec 12 20:13:07 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408387.7226] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Dec 12 20:13:07 thinkstation wpa_supplicant[979]: wlp0s20f3: SME: Trying to authenticate with 18:d6:c7:f9:e7:6e (SSID='OpenWrtP87' freq=5180 MHz)
Dec 12 20:13:07 thinkstation kernel: [ 1256.648058] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with 18:d6:c7:f9:e7:6e
Dec 12 20:13:07 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408387.7428] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> authenticating
Dec 12 20:13:07 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408387.7429] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> authenticating
Dec 12 20:13:07 thinkstation kernel: [ 1256.657632] wlp0s20f3: send auth to 18:d6:c7:f9:e7:6e (try 1/3)
Dec 12 20:13:07 thinkstation kernel: [ 1256.716254] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
Dec 12 20:13:07 thinkstation wpa_supplicant[979]: wlp0s20f3: Trying to associate with 18:d6:c7:f9:e7:6e (SSID='OpenWrtP87' freq=5180 MHz)
Dec 12 20:13:07 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408387.8022] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Dec 12 20:13:07 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408387.8022] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
Dec 12 20:13:07 thinkstation kernel: [ 1256.720533] wlp0s20f3: associate with 18:d6:c7:f9:e7:6e (try 1/3)
Dec 12 20:13:07 thinkstation kernel: [ 1256.722736] wlp0s20f3: RX AssocResp from 18:d6:c7:f9:e7:6e (capab=0x11 status=0 aid=4)
Dec 12 20:13:07 thinkstation wpa_supplicant[979]: wlp0s20f3: Associated with 18:d6:c7:f9:e7:6e
Dec 12 20:13:07 thinkstation kernel: [ 1256.731258] wlp0s20f3: associated
Dec 12 20:13:07 thinkstation wpa_supplicant[979]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Dec 12 20:13:07 thinkstation wpa_supplicant[979]: wlp0s20f3: WPA: Key negotiation completed with 18:d6:c7:f9:e7:6e [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
Dec 12 20:13:07 thinkstation wpa_supplicant[979]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 18:d6:c7:f9:e7:6e completed [id=0 id_str=]
Dec 12 20:13:07 thinkstation kernel: [ 1256.777909] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp0s20f3: link becomes ready
Dec 12 20:13:07 thinkstation wpa_supplicant[979]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-66 noise=9999 txrate=26000
Dec 12 20:13:07 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408387.8768] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: associating -> completed
Dec 12 20:13:07 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408387.8769] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful. Connected to wireless network "OpenWrtP87"
Dec 12 20:13:07 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408387.8770] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: associating -> completed
Dec 12 20:13:07 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408387.8773] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 12 20:13:07 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408387.8783] dhcp4 (wlp0s20f3): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Dec 12 20:13:07 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408387.8930] dhcp4 (wlp0s20f3): state changed new lease, address=192.168.1.115
Dec 12 20:13:07 thinkstation avahi-daemon[923]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp0s20f3.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.115.
Dec 12 20:13:07 thinkstation avahi-daemon[923]: New relevant interface wlp0s20f3.IPv4 for mDNS.
Dec 12 20:13:07 thinkstation avahi-daemon[923]: Registering new address record for 192.168.1.115 on wlp0s20f3.IPv4.
Dec 12 20:13:07 thinkstation avahi-daemon[923]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp0s20f3.IPv6 with address fe80::6b6b:590d:c2f2:58a7.
Dec 12 20:13:07 thinkstation avahi-daemon[923]: New relevant interface wlp0s20f3.IPv6 for mDNS.
Dec 12 20:13:07 thinkstation avahi-daemon[923]: Registering new address record for fe80::6b6b:590d:c2f2:58a7 on wlp0s20f3.*.
Dec 12 20:13:07 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408387.9015] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 12 20:13:07 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408387.9071] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 12 20:13:07 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408387.9075] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 12 20:13:07 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408387.9082] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Dec 12 20:13:07 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408387.9100] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Dec 12 20:13:07 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408387.9103] policy: set 'OpenWrtP87' (wlp0s20f3) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Dec 12 20:13:07 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408387.9116] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: successful, device activated.
Dec 12 20:13:07 thinkstation systemd-resolved[774]: wlp0s20f3: Bus client set search domain list to: lan
Dec 12 20:13:07 thinkstation systemd-resolved[774]: wlp0s20f3: Bus client set default route setting: yes
Dec 12 20:13:07 thinkstation systemd-resolved[774]: wlp0s20f3: Bus client set DNS server list to: 192.168.1.1
Dec 12 20:13:08 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408388.0178] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Dec 12 20:13:09 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408389.0529] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Dec 12 20:13:09 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408389.0532] device (84:CF:BF:93:7A:07): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 12 20:13:09 thinkstation NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1702408389.0540] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
```

As you might see when you were brave enough to scroll through all of that it seems like the system essentially gets into some NetworkManager loop. Also if I pick up the laptop and hold my ear to the bottom I can hear clicking sounds (although I have an SSD disk).

When I saw this NetworkManager loop I tried to go into flight mode before suspending but that doesn't change anything.

I use `6.2.0-37-generic` kernel with Gnome Classic.

Please help me, I really need suspend mode back.